# Determining the number of possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question from the field of combinatorics. Suppose we have a sample with 100 cases (= case 1,2,3...100). My goal is to determine all possible combinations from these 100 cases which include up to 80 cases. So e.g. all combinations consisting of 2 cases (e.g. case 1 = 1 and case 2 =15) but also all combinations consisting of up to 70 cases (e.g. case 1= 2, case 2 = 16, case 3= 17,..., case 70 = 5) up to 80 cases. Which formulas might be used to solve this problem? I would be glad for any references.

Comment: Do you want the combinations themselves, enumerated? it is a programming question better suited for StackOverflow

Comment: This is -- almost by definition -- a sum of Binomial coefficients.  The references go back to the mid-17th century (Blaise Pascal).  You're not going to enumerate them, though: there are over $10^{30}$ of them!

Comment: @whuber: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for finding all $r$ unique combinations of $n$ items is $\frac{n!}{r!}$ where $!$ indicates a factorial (e.g., $4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24$). Since you are interested in a range of $r$ values (2-80), the formula will be $\sum_{i=2}^{80}\frac{100!}{i!}$. Note that $\frac{100!}{80!} \approx 1.3\text{x}10^{39}$, so you're looking at a *very* large number. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve with this, but I think there is probably a better way.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "$r$ unique combinations of $n$ items". The OP seems to be asking for the number of ways of drawing $k$-element subsets from their $n=100$-element base set, for $0\leq k$. To which, as whuber comments, the answer is the binomial coefficient ${n\choose k}$, overall $\sum_{k=0}^{80} {n\choose k}$.